# get the count (integer) of cells in a specific column that have a value, with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to get the count of cells that have values in a specific column?

I need it for 2 reasons.

First off I want to read that number back to the user in a dialog box.

secondly I'm running a function multiple times with the `forEach` method.
I don't want to run it more times than the amount of cells with values, but can't seem to
set the range according to the values count.

keep in mind this column's data is dynamic.
It's not the same amount every time it depends on the user's input.

Note: calling `getDataRange()` or `getLastRow()` don't help because they return the entire sheet's count
which can be more than the column I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getCount() {
  let a=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];}).filter(function(e){return e;});
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(a.length), "count")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! @Cooper does it again!